# How to check if 1 second has passed using custom deltaTime functions [Java]

Tags: java, timedelta

I'm trying to implement a way to create timers in my game. Here's my current code; how would I create a simple timer that checks if 1 sec has passed?

```
public class Time {

    private static long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    public static double getDeltaTime(){
        return (System.nanoTime()-lastTime)/1000000000d;
    }

    public static void updateDelta(){
        lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your need, use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. You shouldn't be using `static`.

```
public final class StopWatch {

    private long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public double getElapsedTimeInSeconds() {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startMillis) / 1000.0;
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you already have, I would do something like this:

```
public class Timer {
    // Last time in nanoseconds
    private static long second = 1000000000;
    private long lastTime;

    // Returns change in time as double
    private long getDeltaTime(){
        return (System.nanoTime()-lastTime);
    }

    // Updates lastTime
    private void updateTime(){
        this.lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    // Public constructor for Timer object
    public Timer() {
        this.lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    // Returns true if a second has passed and updates time,
    // otherwise returns false and does nothing.
    public boolean hasSecondPassed() {
        if (getDeltaTime() >= second) {
            updateTime();
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

This way you could instantiate multiple Timer objects and then using a thread or some other means check them individually to see if a second has passed. The code could also be easily adapted to use a different ammount of time.